# Oracle DB Profile and Connection Pooling / Caching

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

I just took over a project and noticed that they are using a DB profile as such for service accounts used for connection caching

```
ALTER PROFILE APP_PROF LIMIT 
    SESSIONS_PER_USER          100 
    CONNECT_TIME               640 
    IDLE_TIME                  15
   ...
```

I believe that is why we are sometimes getting stale connections, and the "ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off".

My question will be: For middle-tiered applications where connections are cached, are there any good reasons why such a profile would be used for service accounts with such limits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd be hard-pressed to imagine a situation where I'd want to have a middle tier service account with a `connect_time` or `idle_time` set.  I suppose it's possible that someone somewhere has a reasonable reason to use such a configuration-- maybe forcing connections to be frequently recycled is the least painful way to quickly put a band-aid on a resource leak, for example, while you looked to fix the underlying code issue.  But those would certainly be settings I'd look at carefully.

I've seen and heard of cases where someone wanted to set `sessions_per_user` for a middle tier service account where the relationships between the middle tier app server admins and the database admins were strained.  Normally, the middle tier admins set a cap for the size of the connection pool in the middle tier in consultation with the DBA team that makes sure that the database can handle `connection_pool_max * number_of_app_servers` connections.  If the middle tier admins have a history of spinning up new app server farms or bumping up the number of allowed connections in the connection pool without talking to the DBA team, the DBA team may want to set their own limit to protect the database.  I'd much rather solve the communication problem than have a separate database limit.